# Validate xml file contains tags with namespaces using xsd schema

Tags: xml, xsd

There are next input xml-file:

```
 <ns0:HEADER xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns/dummy-dummy">
    <ns0:REQUEST_ID>Dummy request id</ns0:REQUEST_ID>
    <ns0:SOURCE>Dummy source</ns0:SOURCE>
    ...........
    <ns0:DATE>Dummy date</ns0:DATE>
  </ns0:HEADER>
```

I need to write xsd schema to validate it. 
Can you give me an advice how to validate tags with namespaces like in an example above 'ns0'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can write xml schema file and and set this attribute (elementFormDefault="qualified"). This will make sure all elements are namespace qualified.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.temp.com" elementFormDefault="qualified">
```